# What are the pros of getting a curved desktop monitor - for real?

Tags: video, display, desktop

I'm about to purchase a new desktop monitor. My current one is a 23-inch, 16:9 aspect ratio flat monitor, but I am thinking of increasing the size. My intended use is mostly desktop work - authoring documents, developing software, surfing the web - but occasionally also watching a longer piece of video, online or otherwise.

I'm noticing how several vendors are offering *curved* desktop monitors in addition to flat ones. I that idea as sort of a curious novelty, but now it seems these are becoming somewhat popular.

To be honest, I have no idea whether I should prefer these over regular, flat monitors or not. I can see the theoretical appeal of uniform distance to my eyes, but I don't know that this is even beneficial, let alone significant.

I've noticed web pages such as [this one](https://www.ebuyer.com/blog/2015/01/curved-monitors-pros-and-cons/) describing supposed pros and cons of curved displays, but I am not very convinced about . For example:

> **Immersion** – By slightly bending the edges of the screen toward you, curved monitors ... try to replicate the sense of ‘real world’ vision. This wrap effect attempts to fill your peripheral vision as well as focusing the image in front of your eyes. Curved screens attempt to make you feel more immersed in what you’re watching...

"attempt" doesn't sound too well-founded. Also, If I put what should look like a flat document - it will now look warped, and all apps (or the display server) would need to pre-counter-warp things. Do they? I doubt it. So does this only apply to watching full-screen video? Or gameplay?

> **Wider Viewing Angle** ... When viewing a standard flat LCD screen from any angle other than head on, the viewer will often lose out on contrast and colour saturation ... the slight bend in a curved screen actually compensates for the normal distortion giving you a wider viewing angle

Yeah, well, no. If you're not at the center, everything is messed up geometrically, unlike with a flat monitor. And the contrast and saturation distortions will happen just fine on a curved monitor, depending on your angle from each point.

> **Depth** - Curved monitors produce an almost 3D-like picture ... the curvature of the screen enhances your perception of depth. It’s pretty subtle, but it does make a difference next to a flat screen.

If you were screening 3-dimensional content, I suppose that could be true. But - what does a "sense of depth" mean for 2-d content? Which is essentially all we get? Again, other than in gaming, I don't see how there's a benefit here even theoretically.

Other, more critical descriptions, e.g. [this one](https://www.speedupmypcfree.com/blog/pros-and-cons-of-curved-pc-monitors/), explain that the benefit is the ability of focusing on one part of the screen without losing focus on other parts, since they're about the same radius due to the curvature. I could buy that, I guess. However, the same page says the effect will only occur at the sweet spot (center of the circle-section, I guess) and even then will not be noticeable to most people.

So, my question is: What are the bona-fide, empirically-verifiable benefits of curved desktop monitors? And how significant are they?

Comment: This will probably get push-back as opinion-based or too "human factors", but you've got a lot of good research and thought here.  For watching video, I imagine that a big curved screen that you sit close to would provide more of a 3D sense.  For just a lot of text real estate, I could see it benefiting senior citizens, because it gets harder to adjust to ranges of distances.  Other than that, yeah, I'd be interested to see data, too.  Whether or where that exists is another question.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234: I was assuming _factual_ answers exist, rather than opinions, but we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen any truly 'factual' arguments.  Many of them have some facts to back them up, but conveniently forget other important ones that make them irrelevant for most users.

Exact arguments for curved monitors that I've heard, and why they probably don't apply to your usage:

- Immersion: This is really an argument targeted at gamers, because it largely hinges on taking advantage of simulating thing actually being in your peripheral vision (how your brain processes visual information differs between your main field of view and your peripheral vision).  Even there, it usually requires setting a wider than normal field of view in the game, which is not always possible, and really only confers a benefit for certain types of games, and even then it's really only practical for ultra-wide monitors (21:9 aspect ratio or higher) because they're the only way to reliably get stuff outside of your regular field of view anyway.  If you're mostly doing classical office work type stuff, you can completely ignore the immersion argument.
- Pseudo-3d: This actually can be cheaper than real 3D, and doesn't need special support from the content.  Unless you actually like the visual effect, you can ignore this argument though.
- Parallax correction: This is the whole 'same distance to eyes' thing you mentioned.  The first thing to understand here is that parallax is a function of the size of the display and the viewing distance (essentially, how wide your field of view has to be to cover the entire display), so if you view a small display from far enough away, parallax is irrelevant.  I've sometimes heard people discussing this quote the minimum distance to avoid parallax as 80% of the diagonal of the monitor, but that's not universally true, it just happens to give good results most of the time.  How much any of that matters though is really dependent on what you're doing.  Unless you're doing something where viewing the screen off-angle would be problematic, you can probably ignore parallax though (and even if you would need to pay attention, you can manually work around parallax errors pretty easily in most cases).
- Seamless multi-monitor setups: If the display curves *just right*, you don't have any 'corners' in a multi-monitor setup.  This is actually really nice when you're working with multiple monitors side-by-side and have to move between them quickly, but probably doesn't matter for your usage (especially since most monitors don't happen to curve appropriately to achieve this).

Put simply, unless you're drastically changing your usage or your monitor arrangement, go for higher resolution instead of worrying about a curved monitor, you'll get more benefit for the same amount of money.

Comment: The answer "sounds good", but you would really take it across the finish line if you can add some citations.

Comment: About the parallax argument - even assuming the 80% rule is valid (citations would help) - this goes against exactly what you were explaining before: When the monitor is wide enough to put things in your peripheral vision, then you're sitting at less than 80% of screen width of distance. At 80%, the screen edge ends at an angle of 0.558 rad, or about 32 degrees. Nothing in the peripheral vision there...

Comment: @einpoklum That's because the two cases (immersion versus parallax correction) are somewhat at odds with each other.  Current technology can't reliably do both unless you're using actual VR hardware and doing proper 3D, simply because we don't have displays that can show different content depending on viewing angle.  The really hard-core gamers who care about both but don't want to use VR usually use multi-monitor setups with curved displays to produce a ring of displays, which can help compensate for the deficiencies of both problems in single display setups.